# Spring Security Anotation @EnableWebSecurity does not works in Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, web, spring-security, x-frame-options

I have to enable `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` in my spring MVC project, to return this param in to http response header. 
Project is deployed on Apache Tomcat 9.

here is my web security configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }
}
```

This is how I initialize dispatcher servlet

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

In spring security documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#headers) it's mentioned that

> Spring Security provides a default set of security related HTTP
>   response headers to provide secure defaults.

But, I can't see any security header in Response Header, it seems that spring security is not enabled in my project.

[image]

If I add header option manually in to @Controller class method it works

```
@Controller
public class WController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        return "htmlPageTemplate";
    }
}
```

[image]

Please check, What I made wrong. 
How to fix and enable web security properly?

Comment: Because you haven't configured things properly. You have configured the security part but not the web integration. It requires a filter to be registered. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed `filter`, just added new class to extend `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, and it fixed the problem.

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```